# How to control the maximum threads in a very large loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to use multithreading to iterate over a list of servers, and for each server, send a network request to get the server status

```
for s in all_servers:

    thread = threading.Thread(target=s.get_server_status)

    thread.start()

    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:

    thread.join()
```

however, there might be well over 2000 servers in the production, so I am concerned that 2000 threads are bad,

and if it is, how can I control the maximum threads it generate?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

```
def get_server_status(s):
    return s.get_server_status()
pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(get_server_status, all_servers)
```

In this example only 4 concurrent processes will run.

Comment: This gives a  Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed  error

Comment: Sorry! my bad! pool.map gives this error when lambda is used. I have updated my answer to a named method.

Comment: Nope still the same problem  @Muhammad Tahir

Comment: @Chrim are you trying the code in interactive mode? `multiprocessing.Pool.map` does not work in interactive mode. You will need to test it by putting it in a `.py` file and then running like `python myfile.py`. It is working for me in both python2 and python3.

Comment: @Tahir  Hmmm, not sure why, I will take look later. I did not run it in interactive mode